# Array jump to the end algorithm with weights?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, path

Can anyone help me with this problem?

> "A hiker wants to go on a tour for a given number of days. The route includes several places to rest. 
>   How does the hiker has to select his stops, that the maximum daily distance is low as possible?"

Example: 59 km within 3 days including 6 possible rests

Start --(11 km)--> Rest(1) --(16 km)--> Rest(2) --(5 km)--> Rest(3) --(5 km)--> Rest(4) --(12 km)--> Rest(5) --(10 km)--> Destination(6)

Solution:
Day 1: 11 km
Day 2: 26 km
Day 3: 22 km

Comment: This sounds like the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Answer (score 1):

As @MrCoder pointed out in the cooments this appears to be the traveling salesman problem.

This Problem has it's own wikipedia article [Here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

The basic idea is you keep a total distance traveled to each stop go from point a, but to get to point c you have to go to point b, so the total distance to point c from point a is the distance from a to b plus b to c.  You then do this for the point that has the minumum distance traveled from point a, and repeat this for all points reachable from that point until all points in the range are reached, and then the minimum distance that includes all stops and what route should be taken are obtained

Now that the shortest distance between the points have been found we can the find the shortest distances between the day.

To find this we if we are looking for the n days we assume that the days will stop at the first n-1 elements.  we take the total distances over each day and look at only the last day.  If the last days distance is greater than the previous day we assume we can make the distance smaller still, once the distance of the last day has become less than the number of the previous day we move on to the next number.  if at any point a day has only 1 distance stop on that set you cannot go any farther on that day.

So lets use your example as an example the distances are  11-16-5-5-12-10 looking for three days
So divide the days as shown below

```
11 | 16 | 5-5-12-10  gives a total distance traveled each day of 11 | 16 | 32 since 16< 32 we do
11 | 16-5 | 5-12-10 gives 11|21|27  21 < 27 so
11 | 16-5-5 |12-10  give 11|26|22  ok we have now found day 3
for day 2 11 < 26 but adding 11 to day two would put day 1 at 0 distance so we cannot move it from day 1
```

this would also hold true if day 2 would go to 0 elements

**Example 2**

```
8 - 2 - 16 - 6 - 6
8 | 2 | 16 - 6 - 6   yields 8-2-28  2 < 28
8 | 2 - 16 | 6 - 6   yields 8-18-12 18 > 12 day 3 found
8 - 2 | 16 | 6 - 6   yields 10 - 16 - 12  day 2 has one element  day 2 found
day 1 found
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! But I dont get it, how am I able to split up the path into the given number of days? By applying the TSM algorithm I'll only get the given route, as the distances between them are the smalles?!

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution is not quite working...
15-16-6-7-4-17-6-14-8-9 in 5 days results in 
15 | 29 | 21 | 6 | 31
When I calculate it on paper the best result should be:
15 | 22 | 28 | 20 | 17
Any ideas?

Comment: ok out of curiosity if you are able to calculate it on paper why exactly are you asking what the algorithm should be?  If you can calculate what it should be then you already have the algorithm.  So why are you asking about it?